# Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined from google calendar api

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to do calendar.events.delete() in my nodejs discord bot, but it's just giving me error every time. I was using insert() method in the same looking command and it worked!

Here's my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'delete',
    description: "Usuwa wydarzenia z kalendarza",
    async execute(message, args, calendarId, calendar, mongoose){
        const Event = require('../models/eventID')
        const nazwa = args.slice(0).join(' ')
        const nameData = await Event.find({ name: nazwa })

        if (nazwa === null) return message.channel.send('**Nie podałeś nazwy!**');

        if (nameData[0].name === nazwa) {
            DeleteFromCalendar()
        } else return message.channel.send('**Podałeś złą nazwe wydarzenia!**');

        async function DeleteFromCalendar() {
            try {
                await calendar.events.delete({
                    calendarId: calendarId,
                    eventId: nameData[0].ID
                });
                message.channel.send(`**Poprawnie usunięto** *${nazwa}*`)
            } catch(err) {return console.log(err), message.channel.send('**Wystąpił błąd!**')}
        }
    }
}
```

and here's error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined
    at DeleteFromCalendar (X:\BOT\1T Calendar Bot\commands\delete.js:17:39)
    at Object.execute (X:\BOT\1T Calendar Bot\commands\delete.js:12:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: What error are you receiving? Can you confirm you are passing accurate ids to the request?

Comment: i done calendar.events.insert() the same way with the same info, i also have the same problem with edit() method, i'll add error code in a second.

Comment: Can you confirm that the event with that id exists?

Comment: yes,  its stored in database, i used console log to check if its there

Comment: Do you have any other errors in your code? I tried replicating this but I was unable to. Have you tried changing `nameData` to simply `Event.find({ name: nazwa })`?